# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when converting dataframe's index into datetime

Tags: python

I am trying to convert dataframe date indext into datetime.

```
DTSdata_combined.index

Index(['10/28/2021 18:01', '10/28/2021 18:16', '10/28/2021 18:31',
       '10/28/2021 18:46', '10/28/2021 19:01', '10/28/2021 19:16',
       '10/28/2021 19:31', '10/28/2021 19:46', '10/28/2021 20:01',
       '10/28/2021 20:16',
       ...
       '5/27/2021 17:37', '5/27/2021 17:52', '5/27/2021 18:07',
       '5/27/2021 18:22', '5/27/2021 18:37', '5/27/2021 18:52',
       '5/27/2021 19:07', '5/27/2021 19:22', '5/27/2021 19:37',
       '5/27/2021 19:52'],
      dtype='object', length=1951)
```

then

```
pd.to_datetime(DTSdata_combined.index)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-3ad446f69a60> in <module>
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(DTSdata_combined.index)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    808         result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors, tz)
    809     elif isinstance(arg, Index):
--> 810         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    811         if not cache_array.empty:
    812             result = _convert_and_box_cache(arg, cache_array, name=arg.name)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    167     from pandas import Series
    168 
--> 169     cache_array = Series(dtype=object)
    170 
    171     if cache:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

so I check it, access each one element is fine

```
pd.to_datetime(DTSdata_combined.index[1])
Timestamp('2021-10-28 18:16:00')
```

now if I tried to access multiple elements, I got same error

```
pd.to_datetime(DTSdata_combined.index[1:2])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-9ca57df559ee> in <module>
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(DTSdata_combined.index[1:2])

C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    808         result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors, tz)
    809     elif isinstance(arg, Index):
--> 810         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    811         if not cache_array.empty:
    812             result = _convert_and_box_cache(arg, cache_array, name=arg.name)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    167     from pandas import Series
    168 
--> 169     cache_array = Series(dtype=object)
    170 
    171     if cache:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I think something's been corrupted. `from pandas import Series` seems to have gotten a `list`, not a pandas `Series` class. It helps to post running examples so we don't have to cook them up ourselves, but when I create a dataframe similar to yours it works fine. And `pandas.Series` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Maybe your code did `pd.Serise = some_list`. You could print `pd.Series` right before the failing call.

Comment: even I tried pd.Series(index.tolist()), i got same error.Thanks

Comment: @roudan - right. That's because the call that failed was `Series(dtype=object)`. That should be a pandas `Series` class, but from the error message, it has been reassigned to a list. Likely your code did that somewhere. Try making a simple working example. If it starts working, that means the bug is in your code. if you get the same error, something in your install is corrupted.

Comment: thanks, not sure what you meant. any example? Thanks

Comment: Here is a working example: https://pastebin.com/LNVeb1kD. See if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so muchtdelanet, I copied your code and i got same error after replacing index=DTSdata_combined.index.tolist(), if I don't do od.todatetime(), then it is fine. thanks

Comment: You got the same error running just my code? What does "after replacing.." mean? Are you in a jupyter notebook or some other IDE? You need to restart python if the running `pandas` module has been messed with.

Comment: Here is what I did:  import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.DataFrame([], index=DTSdata_combined.index.tolist())
df['converted'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

Comment: @roudan I think tdelaney wants to investigate whether your pandas package has been modified somehow; try run that pastebin example without changing anything & see if it gives an error.

Comment: if I did df['converted'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]),, then it is fine, so I cannot do df['converted'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

Comment: oh yeah, I copied tdelaney's exact code into my jupyter notebook, I got same error. so something wrong with my pandas?

Comment: I run the same code in my another pc, then it is fine. so look like my jupyter notebook in first pc is corrupted. how to fix it? can I run conda update pandas? Thanks

Comment: Is your Jupyter notebook hosted locally or through an online service?

Comment: my jupyter is on locally

Comment: ok,  I updated pandas by doing conda update pandas, then problem solved. Thank you so much tdelaney and PeptideWitch. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries. @tdelaney feel free to write that one up as an answer & roudan can mark it as accepted; we wouldn't have got to the bottom of this without the pastbin runnable example code.

Comment: yes,, pls . I really appreciate it. It is a great finding!

Comment: now I got the same error again after running the same code after few mintes, what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You convert Index of DataFrame to datatime format, so, first, need to convert DataFrame.Index to list.
In pandas.to_datetime, first argument would be int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series.
That's why, please use the method pandas.Index.tolist

Comment: Please give it a try. The problem is that `pandas.Series` has been reassigned to a list somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [pandas Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) isn't a requisite data type of [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

What if you try: `pd.to_datetime(DTSdata_combined.index[1:2].to_list())`

Comment: using tolist has same error. I double check it. I think it is due to wrong data, I found some of date string is like this:  '11/2/2021 14:24',  '11/2/2021 14:24.1'. Does it create problem?

Comment: @roudan - This is why you post running code. Just make a dataframe with an index of a few dates in an index and a junk column just to give it some dimension. to_datetime works with the index, which is easily tested.

Comment: I tested it, that doesn't cause erorr. it should be something else.